# Only the circle moves of my tic-tac-toe program

Tags: python

The following code is the beginning of a tic-tac-toe Python game. I have made two turtles, one for the cross and one for the circle, but the cross turtle doesn't seem to be moving even when the condition is being met.

```
import turtle 

clickCount=0
turtle.setup(750,750)
wn=turtle.Screen()
grid=turtle.Turtle()
grid.speed(15)
grid.pensize(10)
grid.penup()
grid.goto(-300,-300)
grid.pendown()
grid.goto(-300,300)
grid.goto(300,300)
grid.goto(300,-300)
grid.goto(-300,-300)
grid.goto(-300,-100)
grid.goto(300,-100)
grid.goto(300,100)
grid.goto(-300,100)   
grid.penup()
grid.goto(-100,300)
grid.pendown()
grid.goto(-100,-300)
grid.goto(100,-300)
grid.goto(100,300)


cross=turtle.Turtle()
cross.penup()
circle=turtle.Turtle()
circle.shape("circle")
circle.penup()


def clickthingy(x,y): 
    clickCount=0

    if x>-300 and x<-100:
        if y>100 and y<300:
            if clickCount%2==0:
                circle.goto(-200,200)
                clickCount=clickCount+1
            else:
                cross.goto(-200,200)
                clickCount=clickCount+1
        if y<100 and y>-100:
            if clickCount%2==0:
                circle.goto(-200,0)
                clickCount=clickCount+1
            else:
                cross.goto(-200,0)
                clickCount=clickCount+1
        if y<-100 and y>-300:
            if clickCount%2==0:
                circle.goto(-200,-200)
                clickCount=clickCount+1
            else:
                cross.goto(-200,-200)
                clickCount=clickCount+1         

   if x>-100 and x<100:
    if y>100 and y<300:
        if clickCount%2==0:
            circle.goto(0,200)
            clickCount=clickCount+1
        else:
            cross.goto(0,200)
            clickCount=clickCount+1
    if y<100 and y>-100:
        if clickCount%2==0:
            circle.goto(0,0)
            clickCount=clickCount+1
        else:
            cross.goto(0,0)
            clickCount=clickCount+1
    if y<-100 and y>-300:
        if clickCount%2==0:
            circle.goto(0,-200)
            clickCount=clickCount+1
        else:
            cross.goto(0,-200)
            clickCount=clickCount+1   

    if x>100 and x<300:
        if y>100 and y<300:
            if clickCount%2==0:
                circle.goto(200,200)
                clickCount=clickCount+1
            else:
                cross.goto(200,200)
                clickCount=clickCount+1
        if y<100 and y>-100:
            if clickCount%2==0:
                circle.goto(200,0)
                clickCount=clickCount+1
            else:
                cross.goto(200,0)
                clickCount=clickCount+1
            if y<-100 and y>-300:
                if clickCount%2==0:
                    circle.goto(200,-200)
                    clickCount=clickCount+1
                else:
                    cross.goto(200,-200)
                    clickCount=clickCount+1   

wn.onclick(clickthingy)
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: This code is unreadable. Break it down into functions, try to narrow down where the problem is and post the minimal relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the `clickCount` variable to zero on every click. Make it a global variable instead:

```
clickCount = 0

def clickthingy(x,y): 
    global clickCount
    ....
```

> Disclaimer: while this will make it work, it would be generally considered horible style. Try to restructure you're program (as suggested by the comments by yurib and That1Guy).

Comment: While your suggestion will work, its a bad solution. `clickCount` should be an attribute on an object. `global` is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: I absolutely agree. Added a disclaimer.